# WSO2 Identity Server multi-tenancy errror

Tags: wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

When trying to evaluate policies, I get the following error:

**Error while retrieving attribute values from PIP attribute finder : Illegal access attempt to cache ] owned by tenant {[client1.mydomain.com],[1]} by tenant {[client2.mydomain.com],[2]**

This occurs after successfully creating policies on client1, and then trying to create policies on client2.  This seems to ocurr when testing policies on client2 that involve roles.

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of WSO2IS? Did you deployed Identity Server in a cluster? Then this may be a know [issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2052). Actually, this can not be  configuration issue..  This must be an issue with WSO2IS with using caching...  However you can avoid caching issue by disabling it..  Please open `entitlement.properties` file and disable caches..(Specially attribute cache) And restart the server.

Comment: No, this is not a cluster.  It's 4.6.0, on Windows Server 2012 R2, JRE7.  I have noticed other odd behavior pertaining to caching, especially with multiple tenants, such as cached policies and decisions bleeding over from tenant to tenant when polices and users happen to have the same names in each.  I have disabled caching of Decisions, Resources, and Attributes in the entitlement.properties file and so far things seem to be working correctly more consistently.

Comment: Yes.. David.. I guess, Issue that i mentioned can be raised even with a single server.. However, it has been fixed now.. with new version.. Thanks for letting us know this..  I guess you can do your work without caching..  Once new 4.7.0 is release, Please move it